# onSensorChanged never get called in service

Tags: android, events, android-activity, android-service, android-sensors

this might seem as a duplicate question, but the other question have no useful answer, none of the answers are even accepted.

I have a fully working `activity` where every movement of `ACCELEROMETER` is monitored. but when I want to use the same thing in a `service`, the onSensorChanged never gets any call. I have double checked everything. and every question relevant to this, no helpful answer was provided to this question.
this must be achievable.

this is how i call the `service`

```
        btnChangeTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myService.class);
                startService(serviceIntent);
```

and this is the Service:

public class myService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

```
  private SensorManager sensorManager;
  private boolean color = false;
  private View view;
  private long lastUpdate;
  public static final String
  ACTION_LOCATION_BROADCAST = myService.class.getName() + "LocationBroadcast";
         @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Log.v("SERVICE:", "CALLED");
        sendBroadcastMessage("worked");
     return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
```

}

```
 @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
       Log.v("SERVICE111:", "111 CALLED");
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
      getAccelerometer(event);
    }

  }
```

but OnSensorChanged never gets any call.

Comment: answer could be: put `this.onSensorChanged(null)` into your service constructor ... then onSensorChanged will be called as this question is offtopic: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.`

Comment: @selvin that is your point of view. Im asking how to use Sensor monitoring in services. no debugging whatsoever.

Comment: hehehe seems like you have a problem with reading/understanding or maybe me? my interpretation of your question: i'm using _some code_ in activity the same code **is not working** with service ... ok let take a close look at the bolded text ... seems familiar? a little bit. to what? to the qoute from question's closing form ... ok next. do we have _some code_ in the question? ...... ending note: and no, the magic orb is not the one of programmer's tools

Comment: if you double check everything than it just a FSM's Will and you can  do nothing with this (the app will not work coz FSM will not approve it) ... but if you wana an answer then you should provide the code which shows 1. how you setup the sensor service 2. the kind of service normal/intent 3. how you start the service

Comment: @selvin you know Stackoverflow is not you father's property right? check the new stuffs. I highly doubt you find anything useful in those.

Comment: well i did find ... where is `sensorManager.registerListener` call ? i can't find it in `onStartCommand`

Comment: I think you knew from the start that the only diference between service and activity is `sensorManager.registerListener`, right ? you just wanted to teach me a lesson or what ?

Comment: maybe I got the feeling about this, but I don't like guessing ... anyway I'm glad to help you :) and a lesson? maybe one: remeber that if you asking question here the other do not know all that you know - you have to tell 'em ... good luck with coding :)

Comment: @salvin tnx, you saved my evening

Comment: @Selvin Please provide your solution as an answer so that I can accept it. thanks again.